# How to create view and trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, cumulative-sum, dbmail

I am attempting to send a notification email she n a running total reaches or passes a set value (like a sales goal announcement)..:

I have the query to get the running total:

```
DECLARE @TBL TABLE(id int, amount int);

INSERT INTO @TBL 
VALUES (1, 100), (2, 100), (3, 60), (4, 200), (5, 100);

SELECT t1.ID, t1.amount, SUM(t2.amount) as CumTotal
FROM @TBL t1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT *
             FROM @TBL
             WHERE ID <= t1.id) t2
GROUP BY t1.ID, t1.amount
HAVING SUM(t1.amount) < 300
ORDER BY t1.ID;
```

With this query what would be the most efficient means to set up a trigger to fire the dbmail?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

Use job, runs at specific time intervals.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='',
@recipients='',
@subject='',
@body=@message
```

Comment: Gotcha...I understand that, however, I think my underlying problem is identifying when the value is met or exceeded and pushing the email only once.   How do I identify that value in the query?  Especially when the value you can be an exact match or exceed the desired target?

Comment: In what case you want to send mail?

Example : `IF @CumTotal>1000`